Error in Angular Build step in Jenkins
I have not been able to get past the Angular build step. I'm getting Resources not found and I don't know if it has to do with angular or something about configuration.
I appreciate any help
[2024-07-11T14:54:06.466Z] + oc delete all -l lightspeed-build-id=c4550abedf16474f
[2024-07-11T14:54:08.457Z] No resources found





It looks like you’re trying to delete resources with a specific label, but no resources were found. Here are a few things you might want to check:
Label Correctness
Ensure that the label lightspeed-build-id=c4550abedf16474f is correct and matches the resources you intend to delete.
Namespace
Verify that you are in the correct namespace. You can specify the namespace using the -n flag, like this:
oc delete all -l lightspeed-build-id=c4550abedf16474f -n your-namespace

Resource Existence
Double-check if the resources with that label actually exist. You can list resources with the label using:
oc get all -l lightspeed-build-id=c4550abedf16474f

Check Jenkinsfile version
I am quite surprised that the first step in Blue Ocean is different than the first step in the Jenkinsfile.
Are you sure it is the same Jenkinsfile used for the job ? If you click on Replay, can you post the first step run in that stage ?
If everything seems correct and you’re still facing issues, please share more details.
